# Overflow issue with jQuery slide out tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement a message tab in my page footer but I'm having an issue with the hidden div pushing the page down and creating a scroll bar.

```
.alert-message {
      position: absolute;
      width: 350px;
      height: 270px;
      bottom:-200px;
      padding-top: 45px;
    }
    #clickme2 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 65px;
      width: 350px;
      background-color: #971B4C;
      border-top-left-radius: 25px;
      border-top-right-radius: 25px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #clickme2 h4{margin: 25px 0px 0px 25px;}
    .alert-message-content {
      float:left;
      background-color: #971B4C;
      width: 350px;
      height: 225px;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
```

See live example here http://jsfiddle.net/Zu9Sk/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I propose a different approach...

### Added CSS

```
.alert-message {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

### Amended JQuery

```
$("#clickme2").click(function () {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass("is-popped")) {
        $(this).parent().animate({
            'height': '0px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        }).removeClass("is-popped");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().animate({
            'height': '250px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        }).addClass("is-popped");
    }
});
```

So instead of moving the box around we are adjusting its height whilst fixing it to the foot of the page.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/Zu9Sk/3/

Comment: What will happen if the page is long? will the alert box be below the fold?

Comment: Do you want it to be? If not then just add `position: fixed` to `.alert-message`

Comment: The OP is not overly specific, so a footnote about position fixed would make your answer more comprehensive.

Comment: @MarcAudet I have simply adjusted my answer (and fiddle) to have a fixed position.

Comment: A fixed position seems to make more sense for this type of application, good answer, thanks!